# making a pre-trained mxnet network fully convolutional

Tags: mxnet

I wish to convert one of the existing pre-trained mxnet models [available here](http://data.dmlc.ml/) to a fully convolutional one.

This means being able to input an image of any size, specifying the stride, and getting a full output.
For instance, assume the model was trained on 224x224x3 images. I want to input an image which is 226x226x3 and specify stride=1, in order to get a 3x3xnum-classes output.
I'm not asking "theoretically", but rather for an example code :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this example: https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet-notebooks/blob/master/python/tutorials/predict_imagenet.ipynb

You can change the data shape when binding the model:

```
mod.bind(for_training=False, data_shapes=[('data', (1,3,226,226))])
```

Then you can input an 3 * 226 * 226 image.

Another example:http://mxnet.io/how_to/finetune.html

This example replaces the last layer of pre-trained model with a fc layer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed, I can change the input size. but this will not result in the network being applied exhaustively at several locations. The output will remain in the same size.

Comment: If you want to change the output, you can consider change the output layer. http://mxnet.io/how_to/finetune.html